# how to find Xpath for the below xml with namespace for attribute <dto:telefono>

Tags: xml, xpath

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"     xmlns:ser="http://service.web.com" xmlns:dto="http://dto.service.web.com">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ser:service>
         <ser:request>
            <dto:telefono>29932425</dto:telefono>
         </ser:request>
      </ser:service>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

need to find the xpath for the attribute name telefono,
tried all these

```
//*/*[local-name()='dto:telefono']
//*/*/*[local-name()='telefono']
//*/*/*[local-name()='dto:telefono']
//*/*[local-name()='telefono']
//*[local-name()='dto:telefono']
//*[local-name()='telefono']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All your attempted XPath which use `*[local-name()='telefono']` should've worked :

```
//*[local-name()='telefono']
```

**<kbd>[`demo 1`](http://xpatheval.apphb.com/K66M00qtA)</kbd>**

As for `dto:telefono`, the XPath should use `name()` instead of `local-name()` :

```
//*[name()='telefono']
```

**<kbd>[`demo 2`](http://xpatheval.apphb.com/n2aVY7aIx)</kbd>**

By the way, `dto:telefono` is an *element* name not *attribute* name.

Comment: yeah the above xpath works well in the evaluator but doesnt work in my application, could it be because of version mismatch?? i tried in Xpath1.0 and XPATH 3.0 works fine, not sure in xpath2.0

Comment: Should work as well in XPath 2.0 (you can test XPath 2.0 [here](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath)). Anyway, if the problem is not in the XPath itself then its hard to diagnose, since currently there is no sufficient information in the question (what is the xpath processor, how you execute the XPath, etc.)

Comment: Im not sure of the xPath processor, Currently we have configured response xmls based on the telefono no in the request xml in simulator, so based on different telefono no , different response xmls are returned. In this case the telefono no in the request xml is not being picked by the xpath.

Comment: the following xpath works, looks like there was an issue in the simulator, had to redeploy the war file.                                                                                  //*[local-name()='telefono']